# Date format coversion from 2011-09-24T00:00:00 to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can the format 2011-09-24T00:00:00 be changed to DD/MM/YYYY using javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728.

Comment: Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/wJ8Wb/

Comment: as long as the raw date format is a proper one, I think I will use regex too like @Ian's answer

Comment: to save few steps [http://jsfiddle.net/wJ8Wb/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ8Wb/1/)

Comment: @rps Nice update, I didn't think about using `.replace()`

Answer (score 2):

try using this library
Moment.js
http://momentjs.com/

i use it and it does its work nicely